# C++11 freeRTOS questions about queue usage and object design

Tags: object-oriented, c++, c++11

### Background

I'm writing C++ firmware with freertos to penplottingrobot. It's a makeblock XYplotter and the firmware is connecting to mDraw software for command instructions thru USB drivers. MDraw program sends Gcode commands. If you must know, there is a pencil which is controlled by pulsewidth modulation servo, and the plotter is actuated with two axis stepper motors.

For our intents and purposes those mDraw inputs are gotten as `std::string`s and sent to `Gcodeparser::parseCommand(std::string)`.

#### Problem

Is that is there a more elegant solution than the following???

//so the code works as of now, but it doesn't have a good interface or usability

I'm using a `parser_task`, with a `Gcodeparser` object to parse those `Gcodecommands`. `.ParseCommand()` memberfunction takes `std::string` as parameter, and returns a `CommandStruct` by value. `CommandStruct` contains only plain-old-datatypes such as `int`, `enum`, and `bool`. After a legal command is parsed, it is then sent to a freeRTOS queue by value (`CommandStruct` is sent into the queue). The queue is necessary to communicate to the other task, called `execute_commands_task`, which is of course reading this queue.

I have different possibilities for legal `Gcode`s, but they all share only two datamembers in common: `enum {M4, G1, G28 ... }baseType`, and `bool isLegalCommand`.

Otherwise all those "different basetype" `Gcode`s can have a differing amount of datamembers, of differing types (usually `bool` or `int` datamembers, but there are `coordinatevalue`s, `pencilservo` values, `clockwisemotordirectionvalue`s etc...).

So, my current solution which was dumb (but works), was to put all the datamembers as available in that `CommandStruct`. This way you can use that one struct to pass any kind of `Gcode` command into the freeRTOS queue, and still get valid data.

The code is annoyingly ugly because there are un-used datamembers for each `Gcode` command...

But I still have to be able to pass something into the freeRTOS queue which is able to transmit all the required data.

```
#pragma once

struct CommandStruct {
    enum {
        M1,
        M4,
        M10,
        G1,
        G28,
        M5,
        M11,
        M28,
        M2,
        uninitialized
    } commandWord; //any  Gcode command has commandWord (essentially a basetype)

    int commandNumber; //pencilServoParameter, or laserParameter [0,255]

    int penUp; //parameter for M2 command
    int penDown; //parameter for M2 command

    int height; //parameter for M5 command
    int width; //parameter for M5 command
    int speed;  //parameter for M5 command

    bool xMotorClockwise; //parameter for M5 command
    bool yMotorClockwise; //parameter for M5 command

    bool isLegal; //any Gcode command has legality
    int xCoord; //coords for G1command HUNDREDTHS of mm
    int yCoord; //coords for G1command HUNDREDTHS of mm

    CommandStruct() {
        commandWord = uninitialized;
        commandNumber = -1;
        penUp = -1;
        penDown = -1;
        height = -1;
        width = -1;
        speed = -1;
        xMotorClockwise = true;
        yMotorClockwise = true;
        isLegal = false;
        xCoord = -1;
        yCoord = -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: How about a base type which holds a union of 3 ints and 2 bools, and derive the various commands as class M1 : CommandBase, filling in the union after doing some type checking? You could have an emit function or something which would return the data to be put into the queue in the right format.

Answer (score 1):

The first optimization to get rid of the majority of unused members in the `CommandStruct` is to turn it into a discriminated union, like this:

```
struct CommandStruct {
    enum {
        uninitialized,
        M1,
        M4,
        M10,
        G1,
        G28,
        M5,
        M11,
        M28,
        M2,
    } commandWord; // command discriminator

    bool isLegal; //any Gcode command has legality
    //... other members that apply to ALL commands

    union {
        struct {
            // parameters for M1 command
        } M1;
        struct {
            int penUp; //parameter for M2 command
            int penDown; //parameter for M2 command
        } M2;
        struct {
            int height; //parameter for M5 command
            int width; //parameter for M5 command
            int speed;  //parameter for M5 command

            bool xMotorClockwise; //parameter for M5 command
            bool yMotorClockwise; //parameter for M5 command
        } M5;
        //... structures with parameters for other commands
    };

    CommandStruct() {
        commandWord = uninitialized;
        isLegal = false;
    }
};
```

With a discriminated union, the parameters of each command all share the same part of the `CommandStruct` object and the `commandWord` member indicates which set of parameters can be validly accessed. This does require that a `CommandStruct` and all its members (both direct and indirect) can be copied without a copy-constructor.

---

Another possibility is to create separate classes for each command. To pass those through the queue properly, you would have to pass them by reference (pointer) through the queue to avoid that information gets lost.

On the other hand, using separate classes for each command allows you to implement the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and move
the command implementation from the `execute_commands_task` into the command classes as well.

Comment: I think that maybe command pattern design maybe be too late for re-design at this stage... I wish I knew about that pattern beforehand though, it looks like it could have worked well for this multithreaded app... I basically have total of three user-defined tasks. (and the code is for single core ARM cortex m3). Calibration_task runs exclusively first, and makes initializations, and servo calibration and stepper calibration, and notifies other tasks to unblock. Then, calibration task suspends itself. Then regular parse_task and execute_task continue as producer and consumer basically.

Comment: Also, about that union struct thing... In my application thusfar M1 baseType Gcode and M4 baseType Gcode share the same int parameter "commandNumber" which is used to store int value [0,255]. Basically, M1 and M4 shouldnt be used at the same time in the program as far as I understood. Because M4 is  for laser PWM, and M1 is for pencilServo PWM. But I think I can add another variable for each PWM just to be sure, so it's more explicit that way... and maybe rename some of these variables also so they're more descriptive.

Comment: @Late347: If multiple commands partially have the same parameters, there is nothing wrong with having the same parameter name in multiple sub-structs of a discriminated union. The names won't conflict.

Comment: I think this solution looks very nice, but I haven't dared to implement it yet... I looked at that discriminated union code, and I wasn't sure how the code actually works, (I did a little bit googling, but didn't find clear tips). Some questions, that I came up with are as follows: 1) can you actually write a constructor for this struct so you are able to construct any type of Command? 2) can you actually assign CommandStructs into each other meaningfully so that the discriminated union takes into account the changed commandWord? Basically assigning M1 command into un-initialized command etc.?

Comment: @Late347: 1) It is possible to write such a constructor, but probably requires the use of varargs to avoid meaningless arguments for some command types. The normal way is to just assign the various members. 2) The default (compiler-generated) assignment operator and copy-constructor need to be able to do effectively a bitwise copy of a CommandStruct. If all members are primitive datatypes or structs/unions that contain only primitive datatypes, then a bitwise copy is possible and will have the desired effects.

Comment: I think I will only have enum, bool, and int datamembers,being used, so this assigmnent will probably work in the end! I will have to explicitly maybe construct uninitialized command, and when necessary modify that